# Barrinhas de erro-padrão não aparecem em gráfico do R

Tags: r

Estou com uma dúvida no R, e acredito que estou deixando passar algum detalhe muito simples. Resumindo, eu gostaria de entender o efeito da fotossíntese sobre determinada espécie ao longo dos dias, considerando o tratamento de controle e quando está alagado. Desta forma, estou inserindo os seguintes códigos no R:

```
library(sciplot)
library(latex2exp)

lineplot.CI(dados$Dias, dados$Photo, group = dados$Tratamento, las = 1,
xlab = "Dias após a imposição dos tratamentos",
ylab = TeX("Fotossíntese (A) ($\\mu$ molm-2s-2)"))
```

E o meu gráfico está saindo assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O gráfico é esse mesmo, exceto por um detalhe: como vocês podem ver, acima e abaixo das barrinhas verticais de média não estão aparecendo os tracinhos horizontais, correspondentes aos erros-padrões. Já fiz uma busca na internet, mas ainda não descobri se o problema estaria nos códigos do R, ou nos próprios dados.

Alguém saberia me responder?

Aqui está um pedacinho dos meus dados:

```
structure(list(Dias = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L), Tratamento = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("alagado", "controle"), class = "factor"), 
    Fotossíntese = c(20.811, 17.611, 23.528, 16.992, 19.432, 
    16.241, 21.956, 23.096, 17.418, 17.235, 17.019, 19.95, 18.694, 
    18.694, 18.42, 15.58, 17.733, 23.465, 18.694, 18.694, 19.538, 
    16.238, 19.459, 18.187, 20.335, 22.394, 21.711, 21.911, 24.605, 
    18.973, 19.88, 24.215, 22.581, 15.352, 20.668, 20.971, 23.657, 
    17.867, 17.59, 15.735, 15.275, 23.336, 24.377, 21.894, 25.167, 
    24.181, 22.628, 24.065, 23.467, 20.156, 21.593, 19.863, 18.274, 
    17.645, 18.254, 17.98, 17.718, 18.752, 18.688, 18.752, 15.849, 
    20.619, 22.356, 22.733, 23.85, 21.709, 23.127, 23.406, 24.186, 
    23.639, 11.247, 15.003, 8.231, 16.599, 15.781, 15.003, 17.945, 
    19.891, 13.265, 17.067, 21.394, 21.394, 20.935, 23.761, 20.061, 
    22.317, 19.145, 22.059, 24.481, 22.009, 12.136, 14.468, 16.771, 
    17.021, 15.71, 17.551, 17.549, 19.89, 15.71, 12.255, 22.074, 
    22.032, 27.811, 23.771, 28.784, 27.533, 24.704, 26.316, 28.045, 
    26.304, 15.398, 14.873, 14.747, 14.472, 14.805, 12.19, 18.678, 
    14.472, 14.219, 14.873, 18.906, 16.348, 20.681, 18.803, 22.303, 
    18.391, 20.426, 21.736, 21.842, 21.617, 5.177, 4.081, 4.253, 
    5.911, 5.331, 5.177, 5.076, 4.028, 7.121, 5.525, 20.998, 
    17.313, 19.55, 19.028, 20.848, 21.049, 23.851, 22.304, 20.618, 
    21.423, 10.433, 13.203, 11.055, 11.055, 10.362, 11.143, 9.512, 
    9.512, 9.512, 14.764, 19.726, 21.591, 23.5, 25.249, 27.041, 
    26.894, 24.726, 29.029, 27.344, 27.108, 7.02, 7.02, 8.111, 
    9.601, 11.66, 7.92, 7.597, 7.05, 7.02, 7.597, 19.475, 22.128, 
    19.83, 19.482, 18.872, 20.525, 23.566, 24.37, 22.705, 25.147, 
    8.173, 12.566, 10.473, 6.197, 10.473, 12.165, 10.473, 10.473, 
    12.974, 10.763, 22.279, 21.839, 21.988, 23.018, 20.879, 24.09, 
    19.336, 26.66, 25.361, 23.993, 13.627, 11.432, 12.584, 16.917, 
    13.627, 15.154, 14.765, 11.714, 13.728, 12.689)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-220L))
```

Comment: O exemplo não é reproduzível com os dados fornecidos. Recebo o erro `Error in tapply(response, groups, fun) : arguments must have same length`.

Comment: Acabei de editar lá, acredito que agora está reprozível! Inclusive testei aqui e deu certo.

Comment: Eu não consegui reproduzir o erro. O gráfico está perfeito para mim: [https://imgur.com/TpGjqUF](https://imgur.com/TpGjqUF)

Comment: De fato seu gráfico ficou exatamente como eu pretendo que fique no final das contas. Editei a pergunta, inserindo uma quantidade de dados ainda maior, e espero que agora dê certo (ou melhor, que dê errado!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No help da função `sciplot::lineplot.CI`, vemos o seguinte argumento:

```
err.width = if(length(levels(as.factor(x.factor))) > 10) 0 else 0.1
```

Ou seja, se o número de níveis no eixo `x` for maior do que 10, a largura da barra de erro será 0. Caso contrário, será 0.1.

Portanto, como `length(levels(as.factor(dados$Dias)))` é 11, e 11 > 10, temos que por padrão a função irá criar as barras horizontais com comprimento zero. Para resolver isso, basta definir o comprimento destas barras manualmente. Estou colocando 0.1, mas qualquer outro valor poderia ser utilizado.

```
lineplot.CI(dados$Dias, dados$Fotossíntese, group = dados$Tratamento, las = 1,
            xlab = "Dias após a imposição dos tratamentos",
            ylab = TeX("Fotossíntese (A) ($\\mu$ molm-2s-2)"),
            err.width = 0.1)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como era simples! Brigadão, Marcus!